# Makefile shell ignoring sed regexp end of line

Tags: shell, quoting, make, special-characters

I have a folder for various testing of C code, containing many files named `*.c`. My aim is to have a Makefile search for any filename ending in `.c` and add the root of that filename to the targets.

`Makefile`:

```
TARGETS = $(shell ls *.c | sed "s/\.c$//g")
all: $(TARGETS)
```

The issue is that the shell command works as expected in sh:

```
$ sh -c 'ls *.c | sed "s/\.c$//g"'
hello
```

...while it fails with `make`:

```
$ make
sed: 1: "s/\.c/g": unterminated substitute in regular expression
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I tried escaping the `$` as `\$`, which instead yields:

```
`sed: 1: "s/\.c\/g": unterminated substitute pattern`
```

The same goes for replacing the double quotes (`"`) with single quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU Make:

```
objects := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

all : $(objects)
```

See `info make` or `pinfo make` and search for the `wildcard` and `patsubst` functions for more details.  Depending on your distro, you may need to install the `make-doc` package (or similar name) first to get the full `make` documentation.

Comment: `TARGETS = $(subst .c,,$(wildcard *.c))` worked nicely for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to escape the `$`. In `make`, you do so by using `$$`. Your line should be:

```
TARGETS = $(shell ls *.c | sed "s/\.c$$//g")
```

Although this one answers the questions directly, @cas's solution appears to be better.

Comment: How silly of me. I guess all the cunfusion surrounding `make` is somewhat justified. It’s like a shell, but with slight tweaks here and there. Thanks for helping a poor noob out!